# ValueError: Cannot assign object must be a instance

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

I have been trying to register a *ClienteNatural*, which has two foreign keys, one of *Correo* and another of *Lugar*. When making the query in the database to pass the *Correo* object to the *ClienteNatural*, I get this error, if someone can help me. Thank you.
     Momentarily I put a fixed value to *Lugar* just to test, then I will make it dynamic, but that *Lugar* object that I assign to *fk_lugar* doesn't generate an error, just *fk_correo*.

Error:

*** ValueError: Cannot assign "'Correo object (22)'": "ClienteNatural.fk_correo" must be a "Correo" instance.

Models.py

```
class ClienteNatural(models.Model):
rif = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=12)
carnet_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
complemento_direccion = models.CharField(max_length=25)
puntos_disponibles = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
cedula = models.CharField(max_length=12)
primer_nombre = models.CharField(max_length=12)
segundo_nombre = models.CharField(max_length=12, blank=True, null=True)
primer_apellido = models.CharField(max_length=12)
segundo_apellido = models.CharField(max_length=12)
fk_lugar = models.ForeignKey('Lugar', db_column='fk_lugar', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
fk_correo = models.ForeignKey('Correo', db_column='fk_correo', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'cliente_natural'

class Correo(models.Model):
codigo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
usuario = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=30)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'correo'

class Lugar(models.Model):
codigo = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
tipo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
fk_lugar = models.ForeignKey('self', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='fk_lugar', blank=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'lugar'
```

forms.py

```
class Cliente_Natural_Form(forms.ModelForm):
rif = forms.CharField(max_length=12, required=True)
carnet_id = forms.IntegerField
complemento_direccion = forms.CharField(max_length=25, required=True,
                                        validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[a-zA-Z]*$',
                                                                   message='El apellido solo debe contener letras',
                                                                   code='invalid_last_name')])
puntos_disponibles = forms.IntegerField
cedula = forms.CharField(max_length=12, required=True,
                         validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[0-9]*$',
                                                    message='La cedula debe contener solo numeros',
                                                    code='invalid_cedula')])
primer_nombre = forms.CharField(max_length=12, required=True,
                                validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[a-zA-Z]*$',
                                                           message='El nombre solo debe contener letras',
                                                           code='invalid_primer_nombre')])
segundo_nombre = forms.CharField(max_length=12, required=False,
                                 validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[a-zA-Z]*$',
                                                            message='El segundo nombre solo debe contener letras',
                                                            code='invalid_segundo_nombre')])
primer_apellido = forms.CharField(max_length=12, required=True,
                                  validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[a-zA-Z]*$',
                                                             message='El primer apellido solo debe contener letras',
                                                             code='invalid_primer_apellido')])
segundo_apellido = forms.CharField(max_length=12, required=True,
                                   validators=[RegexValidator(regex='^[a-zA-Z]*$',
                                                              message='El segundo apellido solo debe contener letras',
                                                              code='invalid_segundo_apellido')])
fk_lugar = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
fk_correo = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())

class Meta:
    model = ClienteNatural
    fields = ('rif', 'carnet_id', 'complemento_direccion', 'puntos_disponibles', 'cedula', 'primer_nombre',
              'segundo_nombre', 'primer_apellido', 'segundo_apellido', 'fk_lugar', 'fk_correo')


class Correo_Form(forms.ModelForm):
usuario = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)

class Meta:
    model = Correo
    fields = ('usuario',)

class Lugar_Form(forms.ModelForm):
nombre = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
tipo = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=True)
fk_lugar = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

class Meta:
    model = Lugar
    fields = ('nombre', 'tipo', 'fk_lugar')
```

views.py

```
def registroClienteNatural(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    formLugar = forms.Lugar_Form(request.POST)
    formCorreo = forms.Correo_Form(request.POST)
    formClienteNatural = forms.Cliente_Natural_Form(request.POST)
    dataCorreo = {'usuario': request.POST.get('usuario')}
    formCorreo = forms.Correo_Form(dataCorreo)
    if formCorreo.is_valid():
        try:
            formCorreo.save()
        except:
            pass
    dataCliente = {'rif': request.POST.get('rif'),
                   'carnet_id': request.POST.get('carnet_id'),
                   'complemento_direccion': request.POST.get('complemento_direccion'),
                   'puntos_disponibles': request.POST.get('puntos_disponibles'),
                   'cedula': request.POST.get('cedula'),
                   'primer_nombre': request.POST.get('primer_nombre'),
                   'segundo_nombre': request.POST.get('segundo_nombre'),
                   'primer_apellido': request.POST.get('primer_apellido'),
                   'segundo_apellido': request.POST.get('segundo_apellido'),
                   'fk_lugar': Lugar.objects.get(codigo=5),
                   'fk_correo': Correo.objects.get(usuario=request.POST.get('usuario'))
                   }
    formClienteNatural = forms.Cliente_Natural_Form(dataCliente)
    if formClienteNatural.is_valid():
        try:
            formClienteNatural.save()
        except:
            pass
else:
    formUsuario = forms.Usuario_Form()
    formClienteNatural = forms.Cliente_Natural_Form()
    formTelefono = forms.Telefono_Form()
    formCorreo = forms.Correo_Form()
    formLugar = forms.Lugar_Form()
return render(request, 'Home/registroUsuario.html', {'formUsuario': formUsuario,
                                                     'formClienteNatural': formClienteNatural,
                                                     'formTelefono': formTelefono,
                                                     'formCorreo': formCorreo,
                                                     'formLugar': formLugar})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in your form. This should work:

```
fk_lugar = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
fk_correo = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
```

The issue here is that when you say `fk_correo` is a `CharField`, somewhere under the hood django is casting the object as a string. Notice in your error message the triple quotes which mean the ValueError is because you're passing a string instead of an object:

```
*** ValueError: Cannot assign "'Correo object (22)'": "ClienteNatural.fk_correo" must be a "Correo" instance.
```

When you use an `IntegerField` then django figures out that when you pass an object you're implicitly passing the primary key. That's why the `fk_lugar` was working but not `fk_correo`.